# Why is yum re-creating default nginx config file on yum update on RHEL7?

Tags: nginx, centos, yum, rhel, rhel7

I installed nginx via yum package on RHEL7. I added my config as

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/my.conf
```

and deleted the config file shipped with the package

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Recently, nginx package was updated via yum update. Now, the default.conf file is present again. I would have expected that yum doesn't touch default config files if they were changed or deleted.

Is this normal yum behavior? Here some information about the RHEL version and nginx package.

```
root@host: [~]# yum info nginx
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
Installed Packages
Name        : nginx
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.14.1
Release     : 1.el7_4.ngx
Size        : 2.6 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : nginx
Summary     : High performance web server
URL         : http://nginx.org/
License     : 2-clause BSD-like license
Description : nginx [engine x] is an HTTP and reverse proxy server, as well as
            : a mail proxy server.
```

I upgrade the package from 1.14.0 to version 1.14.1 shown above.

```
root@host: [~]# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.14.1
```

Redhat version:

```
root@host: [~]# hostnamectl 
   Static hostname: host.example.com
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: SOME-ID
           Boot ID: ANOTHER-ID
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.5:GA:server
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

If I rename my.conf to default.conf, it doesn't get replaced on a yum update.

Comment: What `nginx` version ? I don't see a `default.conf` file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` for `v1.12.2`.

Comment: @iamauser I added version info to my question. I also tested it again and it really re-creates default.conf file on yum upgrade.